# How can a druid keep ahold of an item while using wild shape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, wild-shape

In the interest of making a bouncing ooze (via [Cave Druid](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Druid%20Cave%20Druid)) that utilizes [Leaper's Libation](https://aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Leaper%27s%20libation) and a level of [Black Powder Vaulter](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Gunslinger%20Black%20Powder%20Vaulter) to jump around everywhere, I wanted to use an [Akitonian Blade](https://aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Akitonian%20Blade) (tiny-sized) in order to boost my acrobatics checks for obvious reasons.

However, I have a set of problems that come with it:

1. Oozes have no hands. (Solved via [Arms of the Marilith](https://aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Arms%20of%20the%20Marilith))
2. When I wild shape into an ooze, the blade merges into me, preventing me from obtaining it's bonuss since I'm not wielding it anymore.

Given that I don't want to waste actions dropping the Arms of the Marilith, picking them up, and re-equipping them every combat, how can I keep ahold of them while wild shaping?

Comment: The Oozemorph archetype for the Shifter might be of interest. https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Shifter%20Oozemorph

Comment: @Isaac I considered oozemorph, but I dismissed it because it's objectively bad and "However, she has no magic item slots and she cannot benefit from armor; cast spells; *hold objects*; speak; or use any magic item that requires activation, is held, or *is worn on the body.*" That makes them unable to do what I want, which is bounce around while in ooze form and utilize akitonian blade.

Comment: it is probably my favourite class, but admittedly partly because it is ridiculous. That said, did you read the errata on it? They can carry objects within their goop, attune to them, and consider them instantly equipped whenever they take humanoid shape via fluidic form. I don't think it quite does what you want still, but a GM might let you make that small alteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the [Improved weapon shift](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Improved%20Weapon%20Shift) feat, which allows you to copy the damage type and special properties of a wielded weapon onto a natural attack from wild shape

> When you apply a melee weapon’s damage type and properties to your natural attacks using the Weapon Shift feat, your natural attacks also gain the weapon special abilities of the weapon, such as the flaming special ability.

It doesn't fully mention abilities of unique enhancements like the Atikonian Blade's acrobatics bonus, but I would rule them as included.

Normally, you could also use a [polymorphic pouch](https://aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Polymorphic%20Pouch) to keep items accessible, but the wording does not include it working when shifting into an ooze. Your DM may still allow it, which is why I brought it up.